# IndexOutOfBoundsException spring batch and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have spring boot and spring batch project.
I'm using spring batch

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and spring boot 1.3.5
when running the project I got this exception:

```
2017-05-08 19:33:28.363 DEBUG 23790 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
2017-05-08 19:33:28.372  INFO 23790 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [--debug, --spring.output.ansi.enabled=always]
2017-05-08 19:33:28.399 ERROR 23790 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sellware.module.ebay.Application.main(Application.java:52) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:145) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:233) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:125) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved By exclude BatchAutoConfiguration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = BatchAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: However this stops the application from running any batch jobs at all.

Comment: I had implement the initialization of spring batch required beans in XML configuration file and it's working because i have many customization in spring batch jobs Beans I declared in xml is ( JobRepositoryFactoryBean, MapJobRegistry, JobExplorerFactoryBean, JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor, SimpleJobOperator )

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm unfamiliar with Spring when annotations aren't used.